# PHP Prestashop accidently change file cause error

Tags: php, prestashop

The project is Prestashop in PHP server. I have accidently change the controllers/front/ProductController.php's name into ProductController.phps. I immediately change it back to ProductController.php. But the system return response code 500 with error after I reload the page:

```
ClassNotFoundException

Attempted to load class "Product" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement for "PrestaShop\Module\FacetedSearch\Hook\Product"?
```

How can I fix this?

(update)
Before I accidently done the wrong change, I remember I also remove the classes/Product.php. When I reload the page and found it does not change anything (not even error 500), I add it back to the system. I guess that could be restore the system automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete the cache files manually from:

`var/cache/prod`
`var/cache/dev`

Or, at least class_index.php, which is available there.

Comment: I have deleted them before I post the question, and it does not work. So I have no choice but post the question... By the way, before I accidently done the wrong change, I remember I also remove the classes/Product.php. When I reload the page and found it does not change anything (not even error 500), I add it back to the system. I guess that could be restore the system automatically.